# How to create union of two directories?

Tags: linux, unix, directory

In case of unix/linux, is there a way to create union of two directories without copying or linking manually everything to a single directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to use [unionfs](http://www.filesystems.org/project-unionfs.html)

> Unionfs: A Stackable Unification File
>   System
>
> This project builds a stackable
>   unification file system, which can
>   appear to merge the contents of
>   several directories (branches), while
>   keeping their physical content
>   separate. Unionfs is useful for
>   unified source tree management, merged
>   contents of split CD-ROM, merged
>   separate software package directories,
>   data grids, and more. Unionfs allows
>   any mix of read-only and read-write
>   branches, as well as insertion and
>   deletion of branches anywhere in the
>   fan-out.

Or another similar option [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Your answer seems much better !

Comment: Having used unionfs to create a read-only filesystem with a read-write RAM FS on top of it, I can say that it's very easy to set up and works with little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

mhddfs is great for making a heap of drives that are transparently linked. It takes some /etc/fstab fiddling, but the solution works great for me

http://blog.mindlesstechie.net/2009/01/19/combine-your-partition-space-with-mhddfs/